# How do I get the object that executed the query from a query handle?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The database is microsoft SQL server.
I've got a query handle (`sql_handle`) from `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`

Is there a way to get that the object the query is part of?
for instance I want to have `dbname.viewname` or `dbname.storedprocedurename`

I know I can use `sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)` and use the `text` field to get the full query but I was hoping to something that gives me the path without having to parse that string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### sure

You just have to look somewhere else. `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` has `object_id` and `database_id` columns you could use to get the schema and object name for non-dynamic statements executed in stored procedures.

You can join `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` to it on the `sql_handle` column to figure out which statements there belong to stored procedures.

Alternately, you could use [sp_BlitzCache](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main) and feed it a `sql_handle` to get that done automatically.

```
EXEC sp_BlitzCache 
    @OnlySqlHandles = 'YourSQLHandleHere';
```

In the interest of transparency, I'm a maintainer on that open source project.

Answer (score 1):

You can `APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text`

```sql
SELECT
...
  st.object_id,
  s.name as schemaName,
  o.name as objectName,
...
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
LEFT JOIN (
    sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
    ) ON o.object_id = st.objectid
```

As noted in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> `objectid` Is NULL for ad hoc and prepared SQL statements.